# What exactly is the test being done when running cld on emmeans, but there's only two means being compared?

Tags: mixed-model, lsmeans

Or is that not necessarily a reasonable approach?

For example, my model is a linear mixed-effects model with only one explanatory variable, such that

```
model <- lme(log(continuousvariable + 0.1) ~ factor(2-levels), random=~1 | block/plot, data=stand)
```

running ANOVA on the model yields a p-value < 0.05 for the factor.

Usually I follow-up with emmeans (used to do lsmeans back in the day) to get an idea of the values by factor, Tukey's p-value adjustment, and cld (I know there's some hand-waving here) but in this case there's only 2-levels being compared. Doing some research on Russ Lenth's FAQ for emmeans, p-value adjustments can't be made where there's only two means being compared. I still get results running emmeans, but it's not initially clear to me what test is actually being done here...i.e., clearly there's no p-value adjustment. For example... output for the following code

```
em <- emmeans(model, ~ factor(2-levels))
multcomp::cld(em, Letters=c("abcdefghi"), type="response") #back-transformation of emmeans

#output is something along the lines of

pm2 response  SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 f1       471 149  3      172     1293  a    
 f2      2765 773  3     1135     6734   b   

Degrees-of-freedom method: containment 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log(mu + 0.1) scale 
Tests are performed on the log scale 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: Compact letter displays can be misleading
      because they show NON-findings rather than findings.
      Consider using 'pairs()', 'pwpp()', or 'pwpm()' instead
```

However... I'm not clear what test was done exactly...? Any thoughts and-or suggestions? Maybe I just didn't dig deep enough or this isn't a logical approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is running the same test you get with `pairs(em)`, i.e. a *t* test on the difference between the means, with standard error derived from the model structure and no P-value adjustment since there is only one test. If the P value is less than .05, you will get two different letters (which is the case shown); and if ghe P value is greater than .05 you will get one letter because they'll be in the same grouping.

I do not recommend CLDs, as you can see in the annotations. Perhaps the confusion it causes with just two means is yet another argument against them.

Comment: Thanks @Russ Lenth. To clarify...is this a pooled t-test we're talking about? I'm struggling to find documentation on what specific t-test (may also stem from my own ignorance of t-tests). pairs() makes me think paired...but...?

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment I posted. I didn't look carefully and was talking about my answer to a different question! But pairs() refers to pairwise comparisons, not a paired t test. And yes, it is a lot like a pooled t test, but not exactly because you have two sources of random error

Comment: Actually, if each block has both treatments, it *is* pretty much like a paired t test.

Comment: Hi @Russ Lenth. Thanks for the clarification. Yes, block represents a replicate (four total). Each have a different number of experimental units in each (7, 6, 6, and 4; dealing with an older legacy study). The factor (2-level) in my model is a soil condition that was observed on a particular experimental unit within a replicate. This is not balanced (soils are going to be what they're going to be). I've already evaluated the treatment effects on the dependent variable for another model, now I'm evaluating the site effects on the dependent vars.

Comment: As a follow-up to my previous comment @Russ Lenth, my goal here was to try and follow Piepho (2018)'s suggestion for reporting cld's (I know...hand-waving here). In his examples, he mentions reporting the test such that 'Means  not  sharing  any  letter  are  significantly  different  by  the  X-test  at  the  Z%  level  of  significance.' Was trying to formulate something similar when reporting the findings and address what the X-test was :-).

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!